# What do I put in pip requirements file for a package not in pypi

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I installed python google visualization api into my virtualenv with

```
pip install -U -f http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-python/ gviz-api-py
```

What do I need to put in pip requirements.txt file so that Heroku can download and install it?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install http://google-visualization-python.googlecode.com/files/gviz_api_py-1.8.2.tar.gz`?

Comment: @arulmr turns out you were very close. I didn't notice you can put the url as is in to requirement. txt. this is the requirements file that worked.

Comment: Put `git+git://github.com/google/google-visualization-python.git` in the requirements.txt. Worked for me on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in your `requirements.txt`:

```
-e svn+http://google-visualization-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk#egg=google-visualization-python
```

**OR**

```
-e svn+http://google-visualization-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk@26#egg=gviz_api.py-1.8.2-py2.7-dev_r26
```

Learn about [installing from VCS](http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html#installing-from-a-vcs) using pip.

Comment: Make sure that heroku supports svn. Better contact heroku support to obtain more information on it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
https://github.com/google/google-visualization-python/zipball/master
```

This will install gviz-apy.py

Answer (score -1):

According to error message

> Obtaining gviz-api.py from svn+http://google-visualization-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk@26#egg=gviz_api.py-1.8.2-py2.7-dev_r26 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
>            Checking out http://google-visualization-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk (to revision 26) to ./.heroku/src/gviz-api.py
>          Cannot find command 'svn'

even svn not allowed.

In this case get source code from googlecode into you project dir and add `.svn` dirs into `.gitignore`. Or create fork on github and work with it.

But before cloning to github read http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 I don't know is it allow such moves.